# CSS3 Rotate and Auto Width

Tags: css, css-transforms

How do I make  to adjust its width by the size of rotated div - currently it gets oversized as if its contents wasn't rotated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .rotate270 
        {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2" class="standard-padding" style="background-color: #ccc;">
                <div class="rotate270" style="background-color: gray; color: white; padding: 5px; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;">Test 123</div></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>               
            <td style="font-size: 10px;"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without using Javascript.
Here's a quick example using JQuery:

```
$('#cell').css('width', $('#cell .rotate270').height());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cR6DF/

Comment: I think you are missing the point - width of the container doesn't change anything. Just make the text twice as longer as it is and set width of the container to 40px, which should suffice - it won't work!